# Some Javascript Not Running in Firefox Android Only

Tags: javascript, android, firefox

I am running a few different things using javascript and jquery on this site:
https://devmones.wpengine.com/

If you visit it using Firefox on Android ( and only Firefox ), there are a few snips that are not running:

- I am using the aos script https://github.com/michalsnik/aos/tree/v2 to animate content on scroll, but that doesn't seem to be firing
- I am using some code to add a class to an element for a sticky header that doesn't seem to be working

Here is the code that adds the class for the sticky header:

```
  window.onscroll = function changeClass(){
  var scrollPosY = window.pageYOffset | document.body.scrollTop;
    if(scrollPosY > 150) {
        headerStuck.classList.add('fixed-transition');
      } else if(scrollPosY <= 250) {
        headerStuck.classList.remove('fixed-transition');
      }
    }
```

But it's not all of the javscript, I am using a lazyloady script lazysizes https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes, and some other custom code for the menu popup that work fine.

I am much more familiar with HTML / CSS issues that differ to browser but haven't encountered it with javascript or jquery before so I am at a loss of where to begin. Any insight into possible steps that would correct this or how to go about trouble shooting the issue would be appreciated, thank you!